# Table Bootstrap doesn't show up well - HTML & CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table here: http://americanbitcoinacademy.com/test/table.html

And I am using bootstrap. Right now it doesn't show the way this page: http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/content/tables/#table-head-options actually does.

Here's my code:

```
<section class="section-padding extra-margin-top">
  <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">

  <table class="table table-hover table-responsive">
    <thead class="thead-inverse">
      <tr>
        <th>Student ID</th>
        <th>Username</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Subjects</th>
        <th>Teachers</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">1</th>
        <td>Mark</td>
        <td>Otto</td>
        <td>@mdo</td>
        <td>@mdo, @sds</td>
        <td>@mdo, Geoms</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">2</th>
        <td>Jacob</td>
        <td>Thornton</td>
        <td>@fat</td>
        <td>@fat</td>
        <td>@fat</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">3</th>
        <td>Larry</td>
        <td>the Bird</td>
        <td>@twitter</td>
        <td>@fat</td>
        <td>@fat</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">3</th>
        <td>Larry</td>
        <td>the Bird</td>
        <td>@twitter</td>
        <td>@fat</td>
        <td>@fat</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">3</th>
        <td>Larry</td>
        <td>the Bird</td>
        <td>@twitter</td>
        <td>@fat</td>
        <td>@fat</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</section>
```

I was wondering what went wrong why I cannot get the same exact styles like this: http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/content/tables/#table-head-options

And how can I attain such the same exact look?

Note: I used bootstrap.min.css already you can use Chrome's inspector element to check it out.

Comment: They're adding some extra element to style the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add bootstrap stylesheet location if you have it in your local system or else give its location from their site`<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>`

Comment: I did that but somehow it doesnt expand to full width. See this again: http://americanbitcoinacademy.com/test/table.html Any idea why the table is not 100% col-12 width?

Answer (score 1):

You can add background color and font color to class thead-inverse.

```
.thead-inverse{
    background: black;
    color: white;
}
```

you will get same look.

Answer (score 1):

you ref bootstrap 3.3.1 in your site, but the sample you compare with is from bootstrap 4 alpha!

Use this css ref for bootstrap 4 alpha:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

It is obvious that you can also download and use it as a local css in your site.
There is a class inside that css to set background of `thead-inverse th` to a dark color:

```
.thead-inverse th {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #292b2c;
}
```

Here is your html with proper stylesheet link reference:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section class="section-padding extra-margin-top">
  <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">

  <table class="table table-hover table-responsive" style="display: table;">
    <thead class="thead-inverse">
      <tr>
        <th>Student ID</th>
        <th>Username</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Subjects</th>
        <th>Teachers</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">1</th>
        <td>Mark</td>
        <td>Otto</td>
        <td>@mdo</td>
        <td>@mdo, @sds</td>
        <td>@mdo, Geoms</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">2</th>
        <td>Jacob</td>
        <td>Thornton</td>
        <td>@fat</td>
        <td>@fat</td>
        <td>@fat</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">3</th>
        <td>Larry</td>
        <td>the Bird</td>
        <td>@twitter</td>
        <td>@fat</td>
        <td>@fat</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">3</th>
        <td>Larry</td>
        <td>the Bird</td>
        <td>@twitter</td>
        <td>@fat</td>
        <td>@fat</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">3</th>
        <td>Larry</td>
        <td>the Bird</td>
        <td>@twitter</td>
        <td>@fat</td>
        <td>@fat</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: I did that but somehow it doesnt expand to full width. See this again: http://americanbitcoinacademy.com/test/table.html Any idea why the table is not 100% col-12 width?

Comment: Edited (add style="display: table;" to table to get full width). please check again

Answer (score 0):

They're adding some extra element with different styles like `bd-example` class. here is the changes I made.

```css
body {
 background: #fff;
}
.bd-example {
    position: relative;
    margin: 1rem -1rem;
    border: solid #f7f7f9;
  padding: 1.5rem;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    border-width: .2rem;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    background-color: transparent;
}
.table {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
thead th {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #292b2c;
}
.table thead th {
    vertical-align: bottom;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #eceeef;
}
.table td, .table th {
    padding: .75rem;
    vertical-align: top;
    border-top: 1px solid #eceeef;
}
```

```html
<section class="section-padding extra-margin-top">
  <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">

<div class="bd-example">
  <table class="table table-hover table-responsive">
    <thead class="thead-inverse">
      <tr>
        <th>Student ID</th>
        <th>Username</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Subjects</th>
        <th>Teachers</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">1</th>
        <td>Mark</td>
        <td>Otto</td>
        <td>@mdo</td>
        <td>@mdo, @sds</td>
        <td>@mdo, Geoms</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">2</th>
        <td>Jacob</td>
        <td>Thornton</td>
        <td>@fat</td>
        <td>@fat</td>
        <td>@fat</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">3</th>
        <td>Larry</td>
        <td>the Bird</td>
        <td>@twitter</td>
        <td>@fat</td>
        <td>@fat</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">3</th>
        <td>Larry</td>
        <td>the Bird</td>
        <td>@twitter</td>
        <td>@fat</td>
        <td>@fat</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">3</th>
        <td>Larry</td>
        <td>the Bird</td>
        <td>@twitter</td>
        <td>@fat</td>
        <td>@fat</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: I did that but somehow it doesnt expand to full width. See this again: http://americanbitcoinacademy.com/test/table.html Any idea why the table is not 100% col-12 width?

Comment: @MatthewMatt  Please remove `display: block` from `.table-responsive` class ` and make it to `display: table;`

Answer (score 0):

Your code work proper for table.if you have bootstrap in your local system. just make sure your bootstrap stylesheet and js path location will be in correct format between head tags. 
or you can give its location from their site:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script
</head>
```

your code work fine with this have a look:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/apwaXJ